# How to select records from table for crystal report in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

i am having table named as product in msaccess database, i was added crystal report into my project but it shows all records from table, i want to filter it between two dates using ms access query but i don't know how to do this... the source code is

---

```
Dim report As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT distinct invoice,productname,amount from product where  date between '" & date1.Text & "' and '" & date2.Text & "'", con)
        myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1)
        myDataSet = New DataSet()
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "outwardp")
        saledtereport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataSet
        saledtereport.ShowDialog()
```

---

i am new to crystal reports please help me out of this problem developers.. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it throw any error? what?  Pls use code block to paste code

Comment: yes sir it shows me an error like "invalid report source"

Comment: try to learn using [parameterized queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx)

Comment: is there anyway to do this simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the dataset as report source 
the report source should be the report that you have created and that you want to show in that report viewer 
and then only you can add dataset to the report

```
    Dim rpt As New pos_rpt_finalreportcr 'name of the crystal report that you have created 
                    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("pos_rpt_finalreportcr.rpt")) 
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt 
                    rpt.SetDataSource(myDS)
                    rpt.Refresh()
```

hope this helps you.